# How to use a table column as slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I would like build single page web site. There will be a table as main content. First column of this table can be toggled by button.

I want to show first column of table only on slidebar, not both of them (table and slidebar).
By clicking to the button, first column of table should be minimized.

[befor toggle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uh6SM.jpg)

[after toggle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gSuR.jpg)

How can I achieve this idea? I am absolutely new to front end concepts, every single answer will be important for me.

```
    <aside class="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-primary elevation-4">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <nav class="mt-2">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" 
                data-widget="treeview" role="menu"
                    data-accordion="false">
                    <div>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                <i class="far fa-user"> </i>
                                <p>
                                    Adelfried
                                </p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                            <i class="far fa-user"> </i>
                            <p>
                                Kalona
                            </p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                            <i class="far fa-user"> </i>
                            <p>
                                Raynard
                            </p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                            <i class="far fa-user"> </i>
                            <p>
                                Wesley
                            </p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                            <i class="far fa-user"> </i>
                            <p>
                                Theobald
                            </p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </aside>


        <div class="content" style="overflow: scroll; padding: 10px">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div>
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Name</td>
                                    <td>AAAAAAAAAAAAAA</td>
                                    <td>BBBBBBBBBBBBBB</td>
                                    <td>CCCCCCCCCCCCCC</td>
                                    <td>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</td>
                                    <td>EEEEEEEEEEEEEE</td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><i class="far fa-user"> </i>Adelfried</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><i class="far fa-user"> </i>Kalona</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><i class="far fa-user"> </i>Raynard</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><i class="far fa-user"> </i>Wesley</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><i class="far fa-user"> </i>Theobald</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You should try something before posting a question here. Have you ? Can you show us some code ?

Comment: I've added some code. I could not make a connection between table and slider.. Now, I have two seperate code section. I have tried to use first column of table inside of slider, but I could not achieve my goal.. @giuseppedeponte

Comment: Can't you just remove the first column from your table ?

Comment: Yes I can. But now the problem is that slider content and table content are not aligned.. Table of content will be grow up. I want the slider and table to look like one piece. If we make it with help of some piece of javascript code, it is completely okey for me.

Comment: If it is possible to show first column of table like slider, it would be solve also my problem.

Comment: They are not aligned in your images

Comment: If you just want your first column to be collapsible and have a different style, you can remove your slider

Comment: Yes, because I could not :) @giuseppedeponte

Comment: This collapsible event is coming directly from bootstrap and I don't think so that I can write it with javascript.

Comment: That is not really so hard. Here I made a basic example in this codepen: https://codepen.io/giuseppedeponte/pen/KKKVRJb

Comment: It looks good. I will try to improve your sample...Thank you. @giuseppedeponte

Comment: If that answers your question, I will add an actual answer

Comment: Yes, it would be also good. I would be glad @giuseppedeponte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want your first column to be collapsible and have a different style, you can remove your slider completely. Here is a working basic example on how to collapse and style the first column:

```js
var table = document.getElementById('usertable');

var toggleCollapsed = function(e) {
  if (table.classList.contains('collapsed')) {
    table.classList.remove('collapsed');
  } else {
    table.classList.add('collapsed');
  }
}

table.addEventListener('click', toggleCollapsed)
```

```css
table td:first-child {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
table td:first-child i {
  margin-right: 5px;
}
table.collapsed td:first-child {
  text-align:center;
}
table.collapsed td:first-child i {
  margin-right: 0;
}
table.collapsed td:first-child .username {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="usertable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <td><span class="username">Name</span></td>
            <td>AAAAAAAAAAAAAA</td>
            <td>BBBBBBBBBBBBBB</td>
            <td>CCCCCCCCCCCCCC</td>
            <td>DDDDDDDDDDDDDD</td>
            <td>EEEEEEEEEEEEEE</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><i class="far fa-user"> </i><span class="username">Adelfried</span></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><i class="far fa-user"> </i><span class="username">Kalona</span></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><i class="far fa-user"> </i><span class="username">Raynard</span></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><i class="far fa-user"> </i><span class="username">Wesley</span></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><i class="far fa-user"> </i><span class="username">Theobald</span></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you again for your fast response.